# C++ How can I get the name of the regular file in the directory without iterator

Tags: c++, boost

first, how could I know how many files in a directory without using iterator?

If I'm sure that there is only one file in this directory, how can I get the path this file without loop the directory?

I know iterator could do it.

```
for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator ditr(dir); ditr != end_itr; ++ditr) {
           count++;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using an iterator? All the underlying os APIs basically use some form of iterator so I don't think there's any way round it

Comment: cause I just want to know if the number equals 1. I think it would be lower efficiency if I loop all the directory.

Comment: Why would you have to iterate through all the files? Surely you can stop when you get to the second one?

Comment: If all you need to check if one or more files exist in the directory, why not do `count = (dir != end_itr)`?  That doesn't eliminate the use of iterators, but it does avoid looping.    Of course, there is the problem of what that means for your program if some process (or user) adds a spurious file to the directory.   Better to assume things can go wrong until proven otherwise, than to assume nothing can go wrong until something happens that makes your program malfunction.